# What is the best value for the parameter class_weight in LinearSVC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, scikit-multilearn

I have a multi label data (some classes have 2 and some 10 labels)and my model is overfitting for balanced and None values.What are the best values to set for the class_weight parameter.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
svm = LinearSVC(C=0.01,max_iter=100,dual=False,class_weight=None,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class_weight` parameters controls actually the `C` parameters in the following way:

> class_weight : {dict, ‘balanced’}, optional
>
> Set the parameter C of
>   class i to `class_weight[i]*C` for SVC. If not given, all classes are
>   supposed to have weight one. The “balanced” mode uses the values of y
>   to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class
>   frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes *
>   np.bincount(y))`

Try to play with the `class_weight` while keeping `C` the same e.g. C=0.1

---

**EDIT**

Here is a beautiful way to create the `class_weight` for your 171 classes.

```
# store the weights for each class in a list
weights_per_class = [2,3,4,5,6]

#Let's assume that you have a `y` like this:
y = [121, 122, 123, 124, 125]
```

**You need:**

```
# create the `class_weight` dictionary
class_weight = {val:weights_per_class[index] for index,val in enumerate (y)}

print(class_weight)
#{121: 2, 122: 3, 123: 4, 124: 5, 125: 6}

# Use it as argument
svm = LinearSVC(class_weight=class_weight)
```

Comment: I have 171 classes in my dataset.How do I set for all of them?could you give me an example

Comment: Your `y` that has the class labels starts from `0` or `1` ?  In other words, the labels of the first class is 0 or 1 ? I will need to update my answer based on your answer

Comment: well I have labels like 121,122,123 and so on.Not continuous but my labels are like that.In total,they are 171. Is adding more weight to a less weighted label same as oversampling?If not,what is the difference?

Comment: see my updated answer. consider accepting and upvoting

Comment: sure.Could you also consider this question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991545/suming-up-two-rows-in-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-in-python