# Sum the values of specific rows if the rows have same values in specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
    a   b   c
12456   11  123.1
12678   19  345.67
13278   19  1235.345
```

or in another format

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>12456</td>
        <td>11</td><td>123.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12678</td>
        <td>19</td><td>345.67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13278</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>1235.345</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first column is the index.I need to add the rows of third column and make it one if second column has same value. Could you suggest me something to do this? Following is what I have tried but doesnt work

```
    a,b,c=df_addweight.iloc[:,0].values,df_addweight.iloc[:, 1].values,df_addweight.iloc[:, 3].values`
    for u,v,w, in zip(range(1,len(a)),range(1,len(b)),range(1,len(c))):
        if a[u]==a[u-1] and b[v]==b[v-1]:
            df_addweight['W']= c[w]+c[w-1]
        elif a[u]==a[u-1] and b[v]!=b[v-1]:
            df_addweight['W']=c[w]
```

Comment: Please format your question in a better way

Comment: @Riccardo Bucco How do I format it?

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Yeah.I read it but to do it ,first I need to be able to edit my question.I am unable to do it

Comment: @SampleTest approve the changes bro

Comment: can you add the data?

Comment: @makis I added it.please check

Comment: @makis To make it more clear, If the rows of my index and second column are same, I have to add the values of rows in third column and make it a single row. Hope this makes the question more clear

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **pandas**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

df
       a   b         c
0  12456  11   123.100
1  12678  19   345.670
2  13278  19  1235.345


df.groupby('b')['c'].sum()
```

Output:

```
b
11     123.100
19    1581.015
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Comment: But I don't want all the rows to be added.only those which satisfies the condition mentioned in the above comment.like if index and second column values match,then add else leave it the same and update the entire dataframe accordingly

Comment: so you want to add the values if the column `a` AND column `b` have the same values?